# Asyncio done() check for exceptions

Tags: python, exception, python-asyncio, future

I am checking if all of my futures are done like that:

```
    futures = []
    for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
        futures.append(
            asyncio.ensure_future(_process_img(i, img))
        )
    in_progress = True
    last_update_at = datetime.utcnow()
    while in_progress:
        in_progress = not all(f.done() for f in futures)
```

The thing is - if an exception happened inside a future it would still be done.
My question is - Can I somehow check for an exception inside a future? (Preferably without awaiting it)

Answer (score 1):

This code is incorrect:

```
    while in_progress:
        in_progress = not all(f.done() for f in futures)
```

It spins a loop that doesn't await anything and therefore doesn't allow other tasks (or the event loop itself) to run. As a result, none of the futures will get a chance to complete and `in_progress` will always remain true.

The correct way to wait for futures is using `asyncio.wait()`:

```
# wait until all futures complete
await asyncio.wait(futures)
```

> Can I somehow check for an exception inside a future?

You can use the `exception()` method on the future object to check whether a future has raised an exception.

Comment: This is not the full code, so don't worry, it works. But thanks for the `exception()` method, I'll try it out